# Имеет ли смысл удаление старой версии Python?

Tags: python

Я установил python3.9.1 на своём vps. Там уже стоял 3.5. Имеет ли смысл удаление старой версии и к каким последствиям это приведёт.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: буквы текстом пожалуйста в следующий раз

Comment: я бы посоветовал скачать Python 3.8 поскольку некоторые модули еще не потдержывают Python 3.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не имеет. Они отлично стоят параллельно. Если вам нужен и тот, и тот — то они друг другу не мешают. Если вы хотите 3.5 удалить, то рекомендую вот так (Debain, Ubuntu, Debian-based, Ubuntu-based):

```
sudo apt autoremove python3.5
```

Но не удаляйте системный питон ­— это может порушит всю систему.

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.9` это не паралельно. а `/usr/bin/python -> python3.9` вообще диверсия в lts дистрах

Comment: @eri Объясните почему? (не, я правда не знаю)

Comment: Для минимального сервера почти ничего не зависит от питона. Но вот например если нужен сборщик пакетов для питона `/usr/share/dh-python/dh_python3` первая строчка `#! /usr/bin/python3` и дебхелпер уже может напаковать что-то глючное.

Графика, например гном, ломается полностью если левый питон стоит как основной.

Comment: @eri А спасибо! Буду знать.

Answer (score 2):

при установке python3.9 в /usr/bin/python у Вас сломались библиотеки в /usr/lib/python2.7 и /usr/lib/python3.5

Выполни команды чтоб посмотреть список библиотек

```
dpkg --search /usr/lib/python2.7
dpkg --search /usr/lib/python3.5
```

И посмотри что зависит от этих библиотек (не удалится ничего потому что зависимости не дадут)

```
dpkg --remove python3.5 libpython3.5
```

Безопасно поставить питон можно через `make altinstall` - так системные ссылки будут вести все также на системный питон.

Comment: Кстати, да. У меня что-то сломалось, но я как-то починил. Забавно. Буду знать